# got UnsupportedOperationException while modifying CopyOnWriteArraySet

Tags: java, collections, synchronization, set, copy-on-write

Studying Java Generics and Collection book by By Maurice Naftalin, Philip Wadler, I left off at CopyOnWriteArraySet section, trying practice while studying to make it stick to my mind, But I faced a problem, let me reveal my trivial code :

```
  CopyOnWriteArrayList<Character> modifiableSet = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<Character>(); 
   modifiableSet.add('a');modifiableSet.add('d');
    for(Character ch:modifiableSet){  
        if(ch.equals('d')){
        modifiableSet.remove(ch); // compiler neglects this, as expected,
                                              // since CopyOnWriteArraySet is synchronous
        }               
    }

   for(Iterator<Character> its = modifiableSet.iterator();its.hasNext();){ 
   Character firstElement = its.next();
   if(firstElement.equals('a'))its.remove();// compiler does not give a damn here              
    // since CopyOnWriteArrayList is synchronous java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException 
    // surprisingly,  wondering If CopyOnWriteArrayList is synchronous,
// why the compiler shouts here ?                         
 }
```

What I my brain understood so far, that whenever modification happens to `CopyOnWriteArraySet`, a new backing array created with the new changes, the question is, Does going through `CopyOnWriteArraySet` through `iterator()` takes place on backing array or front array, If It's convenient to say front array, It sounds reasonable to me `CopyOnWriteArraySet.remove()` works on front array, and `CopyOnWriteArraySet.iterator().remove()` works on backing array, Am I right ?

any flash put into this far appreciated, thank you all .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CopyOnWriteArraySet API is quite clear about it

```
•Iterators do not support the mutative remove operation.
```

This is because CopyOnWriteArraySet's Iterators "rely on unchanging snapshots of the array at the time the iterators were constructed".

Comment: Any alternative though ?